# Dynamic Fetch an Inheritance in Entity Framework 4 POCO

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity

Is there anyway to make a dynamic fetch in entity framework 4

If you have some inheritcance where a and b inherit from c

Can you call one linq query to get a list of a, and b using the data set for c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean ...

```
context.C              // all C's (including all A's and all B's)

context.C.OfType<A>()  // all A's

context.C.OfType<B>()  // all B's
```

Comment: Yes but can you cast context.C to type A in the first example

Comment: If you do `context.C.Cast<A>()` you'll get exceptions if any `C` isn't an `A`, e.g. any `B` would cause that.  You need to filter using `OfType` to avoid that.  If you wanted A's and B's but not any other types that derive from C you could `Concat` the A's and the B's into an `IEnumerable<C>`.